# Mirrored bones move the other side of the armature aswell

Tags: armature, bones, mirror

I searched the questions on the site and I tried a lot of solutions but I'm kinda stuck here.

This is what I'm dealing with
[image]

[image]

When I move a bone on one side, the other side moves with it, basically mirroring it. It is not parented to the other side's bones and I have no clue why it is happening, I tried applying all deformations, I've renamed every bone with .L and .R, I tried remaking the armature, but the problem, for some reason, persists. It applies on all mirrored limbs, fingers included.

Comment: Do you have “x mirror” turned on in the 3D view Properties area (press N to show), Tool tab?

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard It was indeed it! Thank you very much. Is it always on when you make a new project? Sorry if this is a basic thing to know, but just started rigging.

Comment: I don’t know. It’s not the default for me, but I’ve been importing settings from the old blender versions every time I install the new one.